# angularjs directive is not returning jquery object with element.html("string")

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive

I have the following piece of code in a directive:

```
compile: function compile(scope, element, attributes) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, element, attributes) {
            },
            post: function postLink(scope, element, attributes) {
                if (directive.template == '') {
                    var template = getTemplate(scope.field.type);
                    element.html(template).show();
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And it works 80% of the time. But from time to time, I get an error saying that undefined is not a function.

I already did the debug (with console.logs, since, if I have the debug console this doesn't happen), and it is complaining about "show" being undefined.

I assume that, since html(htmlString) returns a jQuery object, sometimes it fails and returns null

Is there something wrong with my code? Or, is there a way to catch the error and trigger again the link function, or any other way that I can make my code work?

**[Edit 1]**

I was able to debug once while failing. the returning object from element.html(htmlString) was a **JQLite[1]**

when the directive works, it returns a **x.fn.x.init[1]**

Honestly, I don't know AngularJS enough to make sense of this, but it may be a clue

**[Edit 2]**

I still don't understand the root cause, that is, why sometimes element was a JQLite and sometimes a x.fn.x.init, but I realized that I don't need the **show()**, so my code ended being

```
                    var template = getTemplate(scope.field.type);
                    element.html(template);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

and that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when jQuery is not loaded yet.

The reason it only seems to fail 80% of the time, is that in all other times you get to that compile function slower, thus giving jQuery time to load.

To fix, simply place the scrip that loads jQuery before the script that loads angular. This will be in your html, but depending on your build setup you might just need to reorder your **bower.json** file.